# What are the most common causes for a surface mount MLCC to crack?

Tags: capacitor, mlcc

What are the most common causes for a surface mount MLCC to crack?  I just want to learn everything there is to know about the HOT MLCC problem

Comment: When???????????

Comment: I am trying to get all possible causes of MLCC failure during production, shipping, installation or while running.  In my case it is a large industrial fan.  Hope that helps thanks!